# Add-on SDK Require Location

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

```
require('chrome');
```

When requiring, from which location Firefox gets the requested module?

Is there any relevant source file for the modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require('chrome');` is a special module defined within the loader. Its source is

```js
    'chrome': { Cc: Cc, Ci: Ci, Cu: Cu, Cr: Cr, Cm: Cm,
                CC: bind(CC, Components), components: Components,
                // `ChromeWorker` has to be inject in loader global scope.
                // It is done by bootstrap.js:loadSandbox for the SDK.
                ChromeWorker: ChromeWorker
```

This is copy pasted from [here](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/addon-sdk/source/lib/toolkit/loader.js#868-872). `Cc` is `Components.classes`, `Ci` is `Components.interfaces`, `Cu` is `Components.utils`, `Cr` is `Components.results`, `Cm` is `Components.manager` and `CC` is `Components.Constructor` which are defined earlier on. You can find documentation for all these on MDN.